# why we do multiple aliasing of high order harmonics

Tags: sampling

The general rule for aliasing.
If my sampling frequency is Fs=800MHz
signal frequency =120MHz.

For the 4th harmonics 480MHz
its 80MHz above Nyquist frequency(400MHz) thus its mirrored 80MHz back to 320MHz.

What about 1120MHz the closest nyquist frequency to it is 2*400 so its supposed to be mirrored
800-320=480 Why we do double mirroring for it?
Why it also mirrored to 320MHz?

Comment: How is 1120MHz harmonically related to anything?

Comment: i ask purely theoreticaly

Comment: That's fine.  The question would make sense if 1120MHz / 120MHz were an integer -- it's not, but you're calling it a "harmonic" -- that does not compute.  Was it a typo, or do you misunderstand what a harmonic is, or what?

Answer (score 1):

Aliasing is more like circular wrapping around rather than just mirroring.  Frequencies wrap circularly between -Fs/2 to Fs/2, an 800 Hz range from -400 to 400 at a sample rate of 800 sps.

120 is inside -Fs/2 to Fs/2, so doesn't need to wrap around at all.

But 480 wraps 80 past 400, and shows up at -320, which looks like 320 if you don't care about phase.

And 1120 wraps all the way around the circles range of 800 Hz, plus another 320, so it shows up at 320.

12000 Hz (12 kHz) would wrap around 15 times and show up identical to DC or 0 Hz.

Comment: for 480 we have its pass by 80 the 400 line.
So by wrapping we do 400-80=320 .
with 1120 we have 800 line which we pass it by 320  its not the same thing they pass th nyquist line by diiferent amount.

Comment: -400+80 = -320, 1120-800 = 320, -320 is different from 320 (if you don't ignore phase info)

Comment: One way to think of it - By sampling at $Fs$, the frequency domain becomes periodic every $Fs$. Any frequencies that were in the original spectrum will still be there, i.e. at their original frequencies, but so will all the periodic extensions of those frequencies. Mathematically, if you have a sinusoid at $f_0$ you'll see tones at $f_N=f_0 \pm N\cdot Fs$, where $N=0,\pm 1, \pm 2, \ldots$